# Strange browser time behavior in Chrome on a MacBook Pro running macOS High Sierra

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, javascript, time

Since time and time zones can be a little confusing, to begin with, I have stumbled onto something truly bizarre in regards to JavaScript and macOS High Sierra time.

While trying to figure out exactly how to express my question, perhaps it is just easier to demonstrate:

In Chrome open the javascript console and enter:

```
new Date(); // result will be something like Tue Jan 02 2018 16:20:14 GMT-0700 (MST)
```

now open date & time preference and switch your time zone (anywhere different).

now in the Chrome console (before OR after refresh) enter:

```
new Date();  // result will be something like ue Jan 02 2018 23:23:29 GMT+0000 (UTC)
```

Note, by the offset, the time is, in fact, accurate, but the darn part is, if you switch your time zone BACK, it still sticks to GMT+000 (UTC). Short of a full system reset, the page (tab actually) seems to be stuck on UTC.

I have recreated similar symptoms in Firefox which are leading me to think this is an OS level anomaly.

I came across this because it seems to effect date/time pickers on several websites I've come across.

Is this a known Mac High Sierra bug or expected/accepted behavior? As it seems to transcend browsers I feel it has to be at the OS level.

This has been one of those “what the HEY” is going on here problems… and "HEY" is not the word my coworkers have been hearing…

Comment: What about Safari? And the “date” command in the terminal?

Comment: Interesting. This is not occurring in Safari. Just Chrome and Firefox it seems...